# HABTM with join Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

hello I have a table name `University_Industry`. It has `uni_id` and `ind_id` as foriegn keys of **University** table and **Industry** table. So meaning university will have many industries and industries will have many universities. I am getting the result successfully by running this query

```
public function getAllUniv(){
    return $this->find('all', array(
        'order' => 'uni_id',
        ));
     }
```

This query returns me universities and their industries.Result look like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [University] => Array
                (
                    [uni_id] => 1
                    [uni_name] => NYC
                )

            [Industry] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [ind_id] => 1
                            [ind_name] => Finance
                            [UniversityIndustry] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [uni_id] => 1
                                    [ind_id] => 1
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [ind_id] => 2
                            [ind_name] => Accounting
                            [UniversityIndustry] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 2
                                    [uni_id] => 1
                                    [ind_id] => 2
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

Now I have another table which called **users** which has `uni_id` also as a foreign key. So I am looking for a query which can fetch only those universities with the industries which are found in users table. So It should fetch only those universities whose uni_id is exist in users table

I have no idea how can I join users table in my query and get the results.

This is how my University Modal look like at the moment

```
class University extends AppModel
{   

    public $useTable = 'university';    
    public $primaryKey = 'uni_id';

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Industry' =>
        array(
            'className'              => 'Industry',
            'joinTable'              => 'university_industry',
            'foreignKey'             => 'uni_id',
            'associationForeignKey'  => 'ind_id',
            'unique'                 => true,
            'conditions'             => '',
            'fields'                 => '',
            'order'                  => '',
            'limit'                  => '',
            'offset'                 => '',
        ),
       );
    public function getAllUniv(){
    return $this->find('all', array(
        'order' => 'uni_id',
        ));
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can join data in your find query.

```
$this->find('all', array(
    'order' => 'uni_id',
    'joins' => array(  
        array(
        'table' => 'users ',
        'alias' => 'UserJoin',
        'type' => 'inner',
        'conditions' => array(
            'UserJoin.uni_id = University.id'
            )
        ),
    ));
```

Here is  [official doc](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables). Hope it will help you

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can I do group by here in users table?

Comment: yes you can groupby like `'group'=>array('UserJoin.uni_id')`